# Error while adding a node in Cluster with Cassandra Version 4.0.7

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with cassandra version 4.0.7, Cluster have 2 DC with 3 nodes in each DC with RF=3.I added a node in one of DC and seed node as two nodes of DC in which it was going to join.During the joining process while node was in UJ state I got these errors multiple time.

**ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2023-06-27 19:43:11,805 InboundConnectionInitiator.java:360 - Failed to properly handshake with peer /IP Address:57364. Closing the channel**

Note:- IP Adress in Error was Error was address of nodes of both DC (As multiple errors was received)

What can we the possible reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult from the information provided to be confident on the cause, but the most likely scenario is going to be around the internode security - run through the following checklist:

- tls configuration is correct / matches on the nodes
- certificates are trusted and in the right locations
- if mutual tls is being used, that the new nodes certs are on the existing nodes as well
- SSL configuration on new nodes and existing nodes match
- Cipher configuration matches between existing and new nodes.